# How to get multiple columns to the power of N in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a single row similar to this:

```html
df <- read.table(text = "Time1  Time2   Time3   location1   Time4   Location2    Time5   Time6  Location3   Time7
2   1   0   2   1   0   3   0   2   1
 ", header = TRUE)
```

I want to bring all the locations to the square like this:

```html
Time1   Time2   Time3   location1   Time4   Location2    Time5   Time6  Location3   Time7
2   1   0   4   1   0   3   0   4   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code golf, anyone?

```r
i <- grep("^[Ll]ocation", names(df))
df[i] <- df[i]^2
df
#   Time1 Time2 Time3 location1 Time4 Location2 Time5 Time6 Location3 Time7
# 1     2     1     0         4     1         0     3     0         4     1
```

(I'm assuming that you did not intend to square `Time5`, though your sample data shows that.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below

```
df[startsWith(tolower(names(df)),"location")]<-df[startsWith(tolower(names(df)),"location")]**2
```

or

```
df[]<-ifelse(grepl("[Ll]ocation",names(df)),df**2,df)
```

which gives

```
> df
  Time1 Time2 Time3 location1 Time4 Location2 Time5 Time6 Location3 Time7
1     2     1     0         4     1         0     3     0         4     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `base R` solution:

```
#Code
df[,which(grepl('location',names(df),ignore.case = T))]<-sapply(df[,which(grepl('location',names(df),ignore.case = T))], function(x) x^2)
```

Output:

```
df
  Time1 Time2 Time3 location1 Time4 Location2 Time5 Time6 Location3 Time7
1     2     1     0         4     1         0     3     0         4     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(matches('Location', ignore.case = TRUE), ~.^2))

#  Time1 Time2 Time3 location1 Time4 Location2 Time5 Time6 Location3 Time7
#1     2     1     0         4     1         0     3     0         4     1
```